Prove that the set of RAMs which do not calculate the identity function is not recursively enumerable.
"Let $M_0,M_1,...$ be a Gödel Numbering of RAMs. Prove that $B\notin\text{RE}$ and $\overline{B}\notin\text{RE}$, whereas $B=\{i\in\mathbb{N}\;|\;M_i\text{ calculates the function id}:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}\text{ such that }\text{id}(x)=x\}$"
So far I have been able to understand that $B$ is not recursively enumerable, because in order to check the condition that $M_i$ is in $B$, you would have to check $M_i(x)=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{N}$ and thus the TM which calculates the semicharacterizing function of $B$ would run endlessly if $i\in B$ or $i\notin B$ likewise.
I find $\overline{B}$ a bit harder to understand; shouldn't it take endless steps to find an $x$ such that $M_i(x)\neq x$? The following semicharacterizing function seems calculable to me:
$\chi_{\overline{B}}(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if $M_i(x)\neq x$ for at least one $x\in\mathbb{N}$}\\\text{not defined}&\text{else}\end{cases}$
Thanks in advance for any tips or solutions!
